# CORS Issue Using jquery-rss to Parse XML

Tags: jquery, xml, rss, mixed-content

I'm trying to use [jquery-rss](https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss) to parse a blog's RSS feed, notably because of its ability to parse within XML nodes for nested HTML elements like images. I have this running perfectly locally (and ironically, since it's usually local development that gives me the most CORS grief):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
  <title>jquery.rss example</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.rss.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
      $("#rss-feeds").rss("https://blog.sonelp.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 3,
        layoutTemplate: '<div class="news-items"><div class="row">{entries}</div><div class="view-all col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12"><a href="https://blog.sonelp.com">View archive</a></div></div>',
        entryTemplate: '<div class="news-item col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"><div class="news-head"><a class="news-title" href="{url}">{title}</a><img class="img-fluid" src="{teaserImageUrl}" /><span class="news-date">{date}</span></div><div class="news-body">{shortBodyPlain}</div><div class="buttons"><a href="{url}" class="button-2 btn btn-primary read-more" target="_blank">Read more</div></div>'
      })
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="rss-feeds"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But once I add it to my website, I get the following "mixed content" error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://blah.com/' was loaded over HTTPS,
> but requested an insecure script
> 'http://www.feedrapp.info/?callback=jQuery16409576896732281612_1640639664174&q=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.sonelp.com%2Frss.xml&num=3&_=1640639664276'.
> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Note that `https` is used for both the hosted site where I'm trying to run this code and the actual XML feed -- the issue is clearly jquery-rss' use of the same developer's [Feedr](https://github.com/sdepold/feedrapp) replacement solution for Google's now-deprecated Feed API, which is called via `http` ("...requested an insecure script '**http**://www.feedrapp.info..."). I tried correcting this in the jquery-rss script directly, to no avail. Any ideas on how to proceed here?

Comment: As the error says, change `http://` to `https://`. Also note that jQuery 1.6.4 is massively outdated (almost 10 years, in fact). Use 3.6.0.

Comment: As my question notes: "I tried correcting (the http/https discrepancy) in the jquery-rss script directly, to no avail." Please further note that I am working from the developer's own working example here, which utilizes jQuery 1.6.4 (not many contemporary RSS parsers out there, still fewer doing what I need OOTB): https://embed.plnkr.co/WQRoCYLld162uplnz1rc/preview

Comment: Apologies, missed that. '...to no avail' what did happen? This is the fix you need to make. Also, if the devs own working example is using 1.6.4, then I'd suggest finding a newer/more secure library as that was released in Sept 2011

Comment: It's making a determination about SSL that prevents the script from running if I eliminate it or if I simply try to add `https` directly to how the feed is called. If the developer's own https-linked example above is working, stands to reason I should be able to get mine to do the same.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I finally did successfully amend the jquery-rss script to only return https:, and it's finally working. If you'd like to post your reply as an answer, I won't take credit for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rory McCrossan got the answer right in the comments above: I had to ensure the Feedr call of the RSS feed I wanted to parse was using `https`, not `http`. It took some doing, but by deleting every instance of `ssl` and the references to it [in this script](https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss/blob/master/dist/jquery.rss.min.js) and then ensuring the constructor for the URL included `https` by default fixed my issue and I no longer have mixed content errors.